# MongoDB doesn't work on Catalina. Keep getting error

Tags: mongodb, macos-catalina

І am quite new to programming. Currently, І am trying to get a grasp of databases and decided to install MongoDB but І ran into the problem and cannot fix it. І have read that Catalina update makes it impossible to create files in the root so І tried to change it from mkdir -p /data/db to mkdir -p data/db. But І still getting the error. What might be the problem and what І am doing wrong? Any feedback will be super helpful :)
[The result І get after І type mongod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piwFD.png)

Comment: "Address already in use" - mongod is already running.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Address already in use'
```

Seems that mongod service is already running.
For further analysis/working use below commands.

```
service mongod status
service mongod stop
service mongod start
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Mohit! І tried all 3 commands and each return "bash: service: command not found"

Comment: Refer/Follow This for installation....   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/